# *ng-if not working inside ion-modal in ionic 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

i am building a mobile app with ionic 5, when I try to call ion-modal that has an `*ng-If` in it, i would get this error

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-header'.
```

The modal is a comment section in comment.page.ts, here is the code for the comment.page.html

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title class="centerAM">{{no_comm | shortNumber}} comment{{no_comm>1?'s':''}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
....
```

here is the code for the comment.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxEmojModule } from 'ngx-emoj';

import { CommentPageRoutingModule } from './comment-routing.module';
import { CommentPage } from './comment.page';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';
 
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxEmojModule,
        PipesModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        CommentPageRoutingModule
    ],
    schemas: [],
    declarations: [ CommentPage]    
})
export class CommentPageModule {}
```

here is the function that calls the modal from the home.page.ts

```
async CommentModal(i, id) {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: CommentPage,
        componentProps:{id},
        swipeToClose: true,
        cssClass: 'comment-modal'
    });
    await modal.present();
    return 
}
```

If i should add the comment.module.ts in the home.module.ts or the app.module.ts, when the page loads, it will automatically load the modal without the user clicking anything, and i also removed the page from the route and it didn't work, please what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 9):

It is likely that your modules are being lazy-loaded. In that case [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) suggest that you should import your modal module (`CommentPageModule`) inside of the module, where you require this modal.

In other words, you need:

```
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ...
      CommentPageModule, // <--- here
    ]
...
export class YourMainModule {}
```

Otherwise, the modal component doesn't get fully loaded.

Quote from the docs:

> When lazy loading a modal, it's important to note that the modal will not be loaded when it is opened, but rather when the module that imports the modal's module is loaded.

Comment: Certify that `CommentPageModule` don't have the `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` implemented, otherwise you will get abnormal behaviors.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue on angular 10, Ionic 5, and the issue resolved by just import

modal page in `app.modual.ts` like

```
import { ModalPage } from './modules/core/modal/modal/modal.page';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
    ModalPage
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

just add the component which will be used

```html
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        UpdatePageRoutingModule],
    declarations: [UpdatePage, DownloadModalComponent],
    entryComponents: [DownloadModalComponent]
})
export class UpdatePageModule {}
```

in modal in your module declarations and entryComponents like this

where DownloadModalComponent is a component which is being used in a modal of UpdatePage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you've imported the `BrowserModule` to your module.

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
....
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
    ]
....
```

Comment: no commonModule, BrowserModule needed only once in app in app.module.ts